# Подсчет одинаковых значений в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Как подсчитать одинаковые строки в таблице comments?

```
+---+------------+-------------+  
|   |    user    |   comment   |  
+---+------------+-------------+  
| 1 | ed         | comment1    |  
| 2 | ed         | comment2    |  
| 3 | edn        | comment3    | 
| 4 | dima       | comment1    |  
+---+------------+-------------+
```

php должен вывести цифру 3, если я хочу посчитать количество строк со значением *ed*. Как мне это сделать?

Текущий запрос пока таков:

```
$cout_user = mysqli_query($this->db, 
                "SELECT id, user, COUNT(*) FROM comments GROUP BY user");
```

И как реализовать вывод количества подсчитанных строк?

Comment: чтобы не было проблем с выводом правильнее писать `COUNT(*) as count`

Comment: и вообще зачем Вам выводить лишние колонки? 
`$cout_user = mysqli_query($this->db, 
                "SELECT id FROM comments WHERE user = 'ed'"); echo mysqli_num_rows($cout_user);`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, дружище!

Comment: можно просто поставить upvote на комментарии (галка слева от комментария при наведении на комментарий) :)

Comment: @Alex `правильнее писать COUNT(*) as count` - а может даже `COUNT(1) as count` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а разве это не идентичные запросы? я читал, что и по скорости различий нет, даже count(1) якобы более сложный.

Comment: Либо неправильно сформулировано задание, и нужно не равенство, а вхождение подстроки (иначе на показанных исходных данных ну никак 3 не получится, только 2), либо одно из двух.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id, user, COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE user = ed
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как вывести количество. Запрос составлен, а вывод как реализовать?

Comment: $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($cout_user);

Comment: @user207012 выучить базу языка программирования, к примеру, для начала

Comment: Ответ неправильный даже с точки зрения синтаксиса sql. Не хватает кавычек.

Answer (score -1):

```
$cout_user = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT id FROM comments WHERE user = 'ed'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($cout_user);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста отметьте Ваш ответ как [принятый в качестве решения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от текста ответа). Это будет означать, что Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос и данный ответ является наиболее подходящим решением для Вас.